# What does "Permission denied" "Id returned 1 exit status" mean?

Tags: c++, c

How do I solve the problem: "Id returned 1 exit status"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<windows.h>
int main()
{
  int P, N, NP=0;
  printf("Introduzca en nombre del producto:\n");
    scanf("%f", &N);
  printf("Introduzca en precio del producto:\n");
    scanf("%f", &P);
  if (P <= 1500)
        NP=P*1.11;
  else 
        NP=P*1.08;
   printf("El producto %d cuesta %d", NP, N);
   getche();
   return 0;
}
```

The full list of errors is:

```
Permission denied

Id returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `ld` is the linker, it means your code failed to link. Paste the full error and it'll be easier to say what actually happened.

Comment: THere is a command, `ld`, on your computer, and it returned the status 1, which means it failed. You should make it pass. A good start might be `man ld`. Ok sorry. Actually `ld` is the linker, and if it fails it means you forgot to link some library at compile time. Each header file you include corresponds to a library that must be linked. Which is why the comment above calls out `conio.h`.

Comment: @Kevin: that's nonsense. A header file doesn't have correspond to any library. It could be a pure macro/type definition file (e.g. `stdint.h`), correspond to the always-included standard C library (e.g. `stdio.h`), or be part of your own program (e.g. `"program.h"`).

Comment: @nneonneo: you're right, in c++ there are plenty of header only libraries, most of boost actually. My bad. It doesn't change the fact that one of the headers he pulled is referencing a symbol from an external library.

Comment: **Permission denied**? Well, that's your problem...some file `ld` wants to write isn't writable. This has nothing to do with missing symbols.

Comment: If that's all the errors you're getting: how are you compiling the source? Are you using an IDE or a script that would hide some output that could be useful? Even seeing the actual `ld` command line would be good.

Comment: @KerrekSB Actually that's true only if P>1500. Otherwise, it's NP=P*1.11 :)

Comment: @nneonneo: Or you don't have write access to some directory in which `ld` wants to create a file.

Comment: Once you fix the "Permission denied" problem, you'll need to change the `"%f"` in both your `scanf` calls to `"%d"`.

Comment: I had this error many times, it is fairly common when you compile from command line, without any IDE. You just simply have to close the program, and try again.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions here, including running as administrator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655471/ld-exe-cannot-open-output-file-permission-denied

Comment: @KingsIndian: Ah, that's reassuring. Let me just increase all my private key bit lengths by 1.11 to be sure.

Answer (score 12):

It does not have anything to do with code. Your operating system simply does not allow to modify a file while it is in use, so the compilation (actually, linking, `ld` is the linker) fails, because compiler can't remove the old executable and place a new one. To solve this, simply close all existing processes running that program.

If that won't work, check your permissions for directory the executable is in, or look for any programs that are currently using it (some systems allow programs to place a lock on a file, so no other program can modify it).

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the executable(.exe) file solved the problem. If you are compiling the code multiple times then it may not able to replace the old .exe file.

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong here:

```
int N;
scanf("%f", &N);
```

Your data types do not match.

Comment: Right, but he's asking about a linker error.  Cannot see one in his code, unless he's hiding something...  The most probable candidate is `getche`, if I have to guess.  Surely the linker error mentions the symbol that is not found.  @user2755844, you have to give us a clue...

Comment: what do you mean?
I speak mostly spanish, so I don't fully understand what you mean?

And nikkie, I swear I'm not hiding anything, not from you, neither from the police XD

Comment: Oh, you're right, I missed the `ld` bit. Well, fix that first and *then* fix the datatypes!

Comment: @user2755844, I'm not with the police, don't worry...  Do you get anything more a few lines above the `ld` error message?

Comment: Only one that says, Permission denied
Now that I see that, I think that must be the main error

Comment: the sizeof(float) == sizeof(int) (usually!), so it's not a _complete_ disaster.

Comment: @Kevin Doesn't really matter that they're equal if he hits UB though.

Comment: @Dennis Meng: you're right. He better read that thing as a string, and `atof` it. This thing needs to be production ready.

Comment: @user2755844 you have declared your variables `P`, `N`, and `NP` as `int`, but your `scanf("%f, &N)` tries to read in a floating point number. That is undefined behavior. Anything can happen after that. Try fixing your code by declaring the variables as `float`. That may or may not fix the problem with "Permission Denied" but it definitely needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

I know the problem is already well solved, but I want to offer another perspective for those who are haunted by  the bug message

> "[Error] Id returned 1 exit status"

So here it is:

If you compile a C/C++ source file with no main function to execute,
there will definitely be a bug message saying:

> "[Error] Id returned 1 exit status"

But sometimes we just don't need main function in the file,
in such a case, just ignore the bug message.

Answer (score 0):

Alt+F2 in your ide... its sometimes realy helps when you forgeting to close "run" window hah)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when i accidently marked my .exe file read only. When i removed it it worked again. (IDK much about programming but this happened to me mayb it helps someone)

Answer (score 0):

if you are compiling in the terminal you need:

```
su
gcc file.c -o nameyouwant
./nameyouwant
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add something to [papeho's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18667811/7267150) answer:

If you are using any antivirus software, this may be the reason.
Some antivirus might be the fact here, probably for including `stdio.h`,`windows.h` or `conio.h` it predicts that working with such headers may causes attacks on your PC

> Probable ways to get rid of it:

1.Try to delete the existing executable file. (Failed because it's being locked on something (maybe antivirus) )

2.Simply rename that file, then rebuild and done (renaming will allow to create another executable file for your code).

3.If failed restarting pc and trying from 1 may fix this.
Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error. And it was a bit difficult to solve because the message says that don't have permission to open the file. But the problem is that the program is still running.

If the program is still running I thought that I will find inside task manager, but wasn't there. So, I tried to delete the file and I wasn't able to delete too. Searching more about I find the program "Process Explorer". With this program I was able to see that my exe file is still running, but with a message saying that the program was suspended. Then I tried to kill through Process Explorer, but without success, because I still don't have permissions. So I close Process Explorer and open with administrator permissions and after all this I was able to kill the process and build and run my file through codeblocks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simply change `int NP=0;` to: `float NP=0;`

Also change: `scanf("%f",&N);` and:  `scanf("%f",&P);`
to: `scanf("%d"&N);`and `scanf("%d"&P);`

And:`getche();` to: `getch();`

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
void gotoxy(short x, short y);
int main()
{
     FILE *ptrFile= fopen("E:\\ENCD_OUTPUT.html","a");
     char a[30];
     cin >> a;
     cout << a;
     gotoxy(14, 4);
     fputs(a, ptrFile);
     gotoxy(13, 6);
     fputs(a, ptrFile);
     getche();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgot to close the terminal window, simply close it and run again.

Answer (score 0):

The following two worked for me:

- Delete the *.exe* file and compile again
- Check if the code is not already running in the terminal (to make sure of this, just close and re-open your IDE/editor)

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem, no matter what, it kept saying the same thing("Permission denied" "Id returned 1 exit status"). I tried many things and this one worked for me.

Go this location [C:\MinGW\mingw32\bin ] and delete the Id.exe file then create new Id.exe file in the same directory.it worked for me.

```
How to create Id.exe file ??
```

Just create a empty text document in the above shown directory and type Id.exe as its file name.

NOTE:Double check if you saved the program or not if you are using the vs code. Sometimes it shows error for not saving the program.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Check first that are you using **flushall();** or **clrscr();** in your program if it is there then for sure you will get that error!!! as it is not allowed in Dev CPP. Use **fflush(stdin);** instead of it.
The problem will be solved surely!!!

Comment: Unfortunately this is not even close to solving the issue. The answers that were given years ago should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Additionally using `fflush` on an input stream is undefined behaviour.