# ld: cannot open output file conftest.exe: Permission denied

Tags: msys2, windows64

Using [MSYS2](http://msys2.github.io/) (version `x86_64-20160205`) on Windows 7 64bits, I'm trying to compile [corkscrew](https://github.com/elia/corkscrew).

Here is the output:

```
$ ./configure
loading cache ./config.cache
checking for a BSD compatible install... (cached) /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking whether make sets ${MAKE}... (cached) no
checking for working aclocal... found
checking for working autoconf... missing
checking for working automake... found
checking for working autoheader... missing
checking for working makeinfo... missing
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether the C compiler (gcc  ) works... yes
checking whether the C compiler (gcc  ) is a cross-compiler... no
checking whether we are using GNU C... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... (cached) none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... (cached) gcc -E
checking for function prototypes... yes
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether the C compiler (gcc -g -O2 ) works... no
configure: error: installation or configuration problem: C compiler cannot create executables.
```

And the content of `config.log`:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

configure:556: checking for a BSD compatible install
configure:609: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:666: checking whether make sets ${MAKE}
configure:712: checking for working aclocal
configure:725: checking for working autoconf
configure:738: checking for working automake
configure:751: checking for working autoheader
configure:764: checking for working makeinfo
configure:783: checking for gcc
configure:896: checking whether the C compiler (gcc  ) works
configure:912: gcc -o conftest    conftest.c  1>&5
configure:909:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
 main(){return(0);}
 ^
configure:938: checking whether the C compiler (gcc  ) is a cross-compiler
configure:943: checking whether we are using GNU C
configure:971: checking whether gcc accepts -g
configure:1006: checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C
configure:1083: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:1165: checking for function prototypes
configure:1327: checking for gcc
configure:1440: checking whether the C compiler (gcc -g -O2 ) works
configure:1456: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  1>&5
configure:1453:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
 main(){return(0);}
 ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: cannot open output file conftest.exe: Permission denied
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure: failed program was:

#line 1451 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"

main(){return(0);}
```

I've tested [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7904469/535203) without any success. Or to be more precise, it goes to the next step (which is failing at detecting my system, which is more a corkscrew's config issue I think) randomly...

This is not a rights problem as I have all the rights on that folder and I use my user to execute `./configure`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ld` is having trouble creating an executable file due to permission problems.  Try building the program in a folder that you are sure that you own (like C:\Users\yourusername) or try adjusting the permissions for the folder you are building in.

Comment: Actually I have all the rights on that folder... I will specify this in the question.