# Vs Code Error while compiling the program

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\Adi\Desktop\Proagrams\C\" && gcc aadi.c -o aadi && "c:\Users\Adi\Desktop\Proagrams\C\"aadi
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file aadi.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

how can I solve this? I am a beginner.

Comment: Perhaps the previous is still running.

Comment: This typically happens (on windows) if the application is yet running – find its window (if any) and close it – or shut it down via task manager.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ld.exe: cannot open output file ... : Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655471/ld-exe-cannot-open-output-file-permission-denied)